# How can I call this Closure in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm still new in Swift development and I'm wondering how can I call This function with the status and results?

```
 func getStatus(completion: @escaping (Swift.Result<SubscriptionStatus, MAPIError>) -> Void )
{
   getStatus { result in
            switch(result) {
            case .success(let subscription):
                switch(subscription.status) {
                case .subscribed:
                    completion(.success(true))
                default:
                    completion(.success(false))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
   }
```

Many Thanks

Calling the function

Comment: It isn't something you call. It's something you implement; the runtime will call _you_.

Comment: I have this function with body completion () and I wanna understand how can I call this function depends on the function signature. Do you have any ideas please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result is such a powerful keyword in swift!
It determines wether the task should succeed or fail.

To complete your function you should call it like this:

```
completion(.success(SubscriptionStatusValue))
```

If the task succeed

Or

```
Completion(.failure(error))
```

To call your function you should do it like this:

```
self.getStatus { result in 
switch result { 
case .success(let value):
/// do something with value 
case .failure(let error):
///handle error
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Result is an enum which can be either:

success

or

failure

So, `completion(.success(value))` or `completion(.failure(someError))`

Comment: Hello, 
Please I need the call function no the body and return.
 ` subscibe. getStatus { (result<status,error>) in {  }`   I'm wondering how can I call it and complete the code to be called, thanks

Comment: I see your code updated but it's really not clear to me what is the question. You are calling getStatus inside the same function body, which cause an infinite recursion